# How to give a drag a view in android giving it a notification panel like feel?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, android-transitions

I am trying to drag view animation in my android app.

[this is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeWfs.jpg) Where there is a **ImageButton** at the bottom.
I want to be able to drag this and bring up a different **LinearLayout** from the bottom of the screen(Which is currently set as **visibility:gone**)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPaiw.jpg) is what I'm trying to achieve.

Currently I'm doing this by a **onTouchListener** .`

```
    this.anim1= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_trans_bottom_to_top);
    this.anim2= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_trans_top_to_bottom);

  expandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layer2.startAnimation(anim1);
            layer1.startAnimation(anim1);

            layer1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            expandButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layerPoss=1;

        }
    });
    collapseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //the same thing...
        }
    });`
```

**R.anim.layout_trans_bottom_to_top**

```
translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0"
android:duration="200"
```

**R.anim.layout_trans_top_to_bottom**`

```
translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="200"
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel